# Motivation to use boost::phoenix::val?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-phoenix

Please, could you show situations, where the use of boost::phoenix::val is indispensable (or at least very handy), not just optional. Boost doc doesn't go far beyond examples like

```
std::cout<<boost::phoenix::val(3)();   //output is 3.
```

When and why one would prefer

```
boost::phoenix::val(t)();
```

instead of just

```
t;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't.

You'd prefer it if you required a (lazy) callable:

```
template <typename F>
void print_three_times(F f) {
    std::cout << 3*f() << "\n";
}
```

Now you can call it using

```
print_three_times(phx::val(3));

int i;
std::cin >> i;
print_three_times(phx::val(i));
```

Also you can use it to coerce any reference to a phoenix lazy actor:

```
std::cout << 3; // not an actor
std::cout << val(3); // a lazy actor
```

Comment: Well, 2 more questiones I should've asked  right away:  1) is boost::phoenix::val used primarily in a tandem with std::cout? 2) can it be used  with non-POD types?

Comment: 1) no 2) Yes, it will copy the value.